# How can I raise a specific link in a navigation bar without effecting the other links

Tags: html, css

I want to make an effect where when one of the links is hovered it raises from the other links without affecting the position of the other links in the navigation bar. But so far I haven't been able to accomplish this and the other links move downward when one of them is hovered.

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbxbJQ

```css
#nav1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  list-style: none;
}
tr > td {
  font-size: 24pt;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="nav1">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">C</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">D</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">E</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">F</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">G</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">A</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">B</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your tds fixed width, your table position relative and your links absolute positioned. On hover, make anchor's top -70px and add 70px of padding-bottom. Check this out:

```
#nav1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}
td {
   width:40px;
}
a:hover {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-70px;
    padding-bottom:70px
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azyOdL

Comment: I like this a lot. Thanks so much for your help! Exactly the effect I was looking for. I'm trying to find a way to make a transition for the hover to make flow a little nicer. I can't seem to find a way to make it work though. Have any advice on which property to use as in the transition property?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a little better if you did it using relative positioning with a slight difference in position (like the example below, where it moves up 5px).

```css
#nav1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  list-style: none;
}
tr > td {
  font-size: 24pt;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  top:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="nav1">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">C</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">D</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">E</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">F</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">G</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">A</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">B</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```